# How do I 'fork' a community module so as to be maintainable?

Tags: code-reuse

I want to quickly get started with a community module, one that has its own backend tables and plenty else. I need a few extra columns in those tables and a few modifications to the template files. I would also like the community module to be upgradeable.

Currently the community module is on version 1.2.3.4, I can put my own sql file in there with 1.2.3.5, update the config.xml accordingly and be good to go. However another developer is going to come along and wonder what the reason was for this 'upgrade'. They may even pull down the latest version of the official community module, to then find it too wants to upgrade to 1.2.3.5, which it won't be able to do.

Also, do I make any of my changes in the 'local' namespace or stick with the module's 'community' structure?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest in this case is to make your own "local" module that depends on this community module. In your module you can make your own specific changes and then not have to worry about errors when updating the "community" module.

Of course this method is not 100% fool-proof as the updates to the "community" module could still have a negative affect on your "local" module, but heck this is why we have testing right :)